# QCombobox background color is faded

Tags: qcombobox, qt6

Consider the following code

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(QCombobox LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS REQUIRED Core Widgets)

set(SOURCE_FILES
  main.cpp
  mainwindow.cpp
  )

add_executable(QCombobox ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(QCombobox PRIVATE
  Qt6::Core
  Qt6::Widgets)
```

*main.cpp*

```cpp
#include <QApplication>

#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

*mainwindow.h*

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
  
  inline const static QStringList SourceList =
    QStringList { "00", "01", "02" };
  
  void comboBoxModified(int index);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```cpp
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
  
  QComboBox *comboBox = new QComboBox(this);

    comboBox->addItems(SourceList);
    comboBox->show();

    comboBox->setStyleSheet("QComboBox QAbstractItemView {"
                 "  border: 1px solid grey;"
                 "  background: green;"
                 "}"
                 ""
                 "QComboBox {"
                 "  background-color: red;"
                 "}");

    connect(comboBox, QOverload<int>::of(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),
            this, &MainWindow::comboBoxModified);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void MainWindow::comboBoxModified(int index)
{
  qDebug() << index << "is chosen";
}
```

I compile this example using Qt 6.5. And here is what I get

[image]

The red colour is faded. If I click on the combobox, I get the expected "red colour", as shown on this screenshot:

[image]

It might be linked to my operating system (I use Ubuntu 22.04).

Did you get the same result as I did?

Do you have any idea how to force the red colour not to be faded?

Comment: I can reproduce this, Qt 6.5.0, KDE Neon (which is based on Ubuntu).

Comment: Could you use this as a minimal reproducible example? `#include <QApplication>#include <QComboBox>int main(int argc,char*argv[]){QApplication a(argc, argv);QComboBox b;b.addItem("a");b.setStyleSheet("background: red;");b.show();return a.exec();}`, the smaller the better.

Comment: And this happens to all buttons, unless you set them flat, in which case, you get the normal red.