# QPushButton background color always looks the same in Qt6 regardless of alpha value

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt6, qpushbutton

I am writing an application where I'm trying to apply a custom color to a `QPushButton`. Example code is shown below:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    auto* const mainWindow = new QMainWindow;

    auto* const pushButton = new QPushButton("Click me!");

    auto palette = QPalette();
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Button, QColor(255, 0, 0, 50));
    pushButton->setAutoFillBackground(true);
    pushButton->setPalette(palette);

    mainWindow->setCentralWidget(pushButton);
    mainWindow->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

project(ExampleProject LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(ExampleProject
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(ExampleProject
    PRIVATE Qt::Widgets
)
```

In the example above, a red color is applied to the button, using a lower alpha value. When compiling the code using Qt5, the following ui is generated:

[image: Example Qt5]

If the alpha value is adjusted, this is also visible. If the same application is compiled using Qt6, however, it looks like this:

[image: Example Qt6]

As you can see, the button color is the desired red. However, the rendered alpha value is always the maximum value. If I try to change the alpha value in the code, it does not change the visual outcome.

Am I using the `QPalette` instance in the wrong way, or has something changed between Qt5 and Qt6 regarding the palette handling? Or is this maybe a bug?

I am using Qt 5.15/6.2 and KDE Plasma 5.27 as desktop environment.

Comment: Same as here: [QCombobox background color is faded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76237428/qcombobox-background-color-is-faded#comment134445072_76237428). "Fusion" style uses a gradient composed of lighter colors for none-flat buttons, perhaps [this is where it happens](https://codebrowser.dev/qt6/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qfusionstyle.cpp.html#851). If it works for you, try setting the button flat, or set its style to "Windows".

Comment: @A.R.M Both functions work. However, this is not really the desired style that I want to use... and is this a bug which should be filed to Qt?

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but I don't think so. As I said, this is probably the intended behavior, as seen in the source code of QFusionStyle.

Comment: I get what you mean, but I cannot really understand how this should be desired behavior. If the color stays the same regardless of the alpha value and if it was different for Qt5, it looks like a bug (or at least an oversight) to me. Meanwhile, I may have to experiment with the flat option or the windows style... maybe I can counter the flatness effect somehow.

Comment: Understandable yes, which is why I am not sure. You can still file a bug report to confirm, or seek more help in the Qt Forum.

Comment: "*maybe I can counter the flatness effect somehow*", perhaps too simple, but try this stylesheet: `"background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop: 0 rgba(255,0,0, 100), stop: 1 rgba(255,0,0, 50))"`. It just uses a QLinearGradient with two reds, the lighter one just has a higher alpha value.

Comment: I filed a bug report and reported it:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-122781

In the meantime, I'll take a look at the stylesheet option.